# Using ForkJoinPool.commonPool() in place of RxJava's computation scheduler

Tags: concurrency, rx-java2, reactive-streams

I'm currently implementing a small subset of RxJava2's API for a personal project. I have a listener-based API and I started writing the code to wrap my listener and implementing `Flowable.create()`:

```
public class EventBus {
    private final Flowable<Event> events;

    public EventBus(MyApi api) {
        this.events = Flowable.create(emitter -> {
            Callback listener = new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(Event event) {
                    emitter.onNext(event);
                }
            };
            api.addListener(listener);
            // TODO api.removeListener(listener)
        }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);
    }
}.
```

I ran a quick test and it worked just fine, but I realized it is **single threaded**. No biggie: it is actually RxJava's design to be single threaded unless specifying a `Scheduler`.

Per RxJava2's documentation, I decided to chain a `Flowable.subscribeOn()` call, which I will call with a `Scheduler.computation()` argument.

So I moved on to implementing `Flowable.subscribeOn()` and `Scheduler.computation()`, and this is where I'm trying to wrap my head around: I've seen in various places that Java's `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` is recommended to run computation tasks on, But RxJava2 doesn't use it. My main questions would be:

- Would this be a good fit for my very basic reactive implementation?
- Why did RxJava2 choose to implement its own pool instead of using this one?
- Are there any problems with this approach that I should be aware of to make my life easier down the road?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would this be a good fit for my very basic reactive implementation?

Writing adapters to traditional callback apis is somewhat common, assuming there isn't one written already.

> Why did RxJava2 choose to implement its own pool instead of using this one?

RxJava always targeted Java 6 and up and `ForkJoinPool` is Java 7. Note that `commonPool` sometimes executes work on the caller thread and doesn't go async. We had many unit tests hang on a CI server due to same-pool deadlock.

> implementing a small subset of RxJava2's API
>   Are there any problems with this approach that I should be aware of to make my life easier down the road?

What do you mean by that? Are you trying to reimplement RxJava 2, the library, or you are **using** and **applying** existing operators in your code?

If the latter and apart from the caveat with `commonPool`, it depends on what you are trying to interface with.

Comment: This is a great starting point, thanks! I am reimplementing the operators that I need (just a bunch for now), but following RxJava2's APIs and semantics in case I want to switch to using the library in the future. It also makes my life easier when trying to understand how everything works and searching for examples online :).
Your note on `commonPool` executing work on the current thread is exactly one of those problems I wasn't aware of, thanks a lot! I'll take note of that.

Comment: Sounds great! This is how I learned reactive programming 7-8 years ago, with the difference that there were no sources available to Rx.NET, only a handful of videos. I had to experiment through it by writing and running a sequence in C#, then trying to reproduce the same effects in Java.

Comment: Thanks for being here for people like me, going through similar experiences as you did. And thanks for writing super-clear code to learn from in RxJava :).